# Android: No pop up on click in webview on 2.X.X or lower

Tags: android, webview, popup

I have been working to create an app from a website.  Everything seems to work fine on devices running *3.x* and higher, but on devices with *2.x.x* or lower I have an issue.  The issue boils down to this: on the website when you click on a button to attach a file it opens a pop up window to select the file.  Only in the app it clears the screen and only gives a white background.

So I'm wondering what I need to do to get the pop up window to work on Android *2.x.x*.

Would it be a `webView.getSettings` line or would I possibly have to add something to the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` function in the `setWebViewClient` function?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
final Activity activity = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Browser"),
                    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg);
        }                   

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg);
        }     


        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
         }

        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm){
            Log.d("MyApplication", cm.message() + " -- From line "
            + cm.lineNumber() + " of "
            + cm.sourceId() );
            return true;
            }

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
                activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        } 

    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl("http://example.com");
}
```

Comment: You should really add more details to your answer, such as appropriate code, some images of the current results and what you want to achieve, etc.

Comment: So I figured out the issue related to my problem.  It has to do wit hthe shouldOverrideUrlLoading().  What I ended up having to do was cut the view.loadUrl(url); line out and then change the return to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem was in changing the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() to the following:

```
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
```